# Applescript to launch file from current folder?

Tags: applescript

How does one open a file in the same folder as the AppleScript code? Something along these lines?

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    open "file.avi"
end tell
```

(which doesn't work).
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder"
    open file "somefile.txt" of folder of (file (path to me))
end tell
```

(only works once you've saved the script - otherwise "path to me" goes to the script editor)

Comment: Great. The `file` before `path to me` is not needed, though (as of at least OS X 10.8) - `path to me` returns an `alias` whose `folder` (or `container`) property can be queried directly.