# Make my applescript process specified files in the current directory?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, applescript

I need to generate PDFs from word files regularly, and I'm getting tired of doing it by hand.

Manually, all I do is open a file, and click "Save as PDF". So, one would think applescript would be a nice easy way to do this.  [If you have another approach than applescript, I'm open to it.]

I'm almost there, the following script works, except the full path is hard coded.

```
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open file "Macintosh HD:Users:me:repos:training:class:Activities:ActivityGuide.docx"
    set doc to document "ActivityGuide.docx"
    save as doc file name "Macintosh HD:Users:me:repos:training:class:Activities:ActivityGuide.pdf" file format format PDF
end tell
```

I need it to work for other people, on other machines, so the username and other parts of the path may change. If I could just do this from the current directory for the script, I'd be set.

I found this: [Applescript to launch file from current folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003699/applescript-to-launch-file-from-current-folder)

```
tell application "Finder"
    open file "somefile.txt" of folder of (file (path to me))
end tell
```

Which works for opening an app from the current directory in Word, via Finder, but I think I need to open it with an application of "Microsoft Word", if I'm going to use "Save As". But this method of opening doesn't work if I change the application for "Finder" to "Microsoft Word".

Any suggestions welcome. 
[edit: clarity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
set x to path to me
tell application "Finder" to set tFile to (file "ActivityGuide.docx" of (container of x)) as alias

set newFile to (text 1 thru -5 of (tFile as string)) & "pdf"
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open tFile
    tell document 1
        save as file name newFile file format format PDF
        close saving no
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that might be helpful to you is under System Preferences:Keyboard:Shortcuts: App Shortcuts:All Applications

Make a shortcut that is named "Save as PDF..." assign the shortcut to command+P since most applications that is the shortcut for print, then just press it twice and it will prompt you to save it as a PDF (I got that tip from David Sparks) and depending on the application it will default to where the file was opened up from.  You can also set that with the application Default Folder X.

Hopefully that is a bit more of a global solution for other problems but it looks like you already have the answer to this isolated problem.