# How to tell Applescript to open a file in the same directory as the script

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "SpriteBuilder" to activate
tell application "SpriteBuilder"
    open "portrait.spritebuilder"
end tell
```

The `portrait.spritebuilder` directory is in the same directory as the script. I think I need an absolute path, but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003699/applescript-to-launch-file-from-current-folder) suggestion, but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked answer should work. Did you put it in a Finder block? Like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myFolder to container of (path to me) as text
end tell

tell application "SpriteBuilder"
    activate
    open myFolder & "portrait.spritebuilder"
end tell
```